# How do you assign a value to an input field in HTML?

Tags: html, jinja2

How do you assign a value to an input field in HTML, this is a python and jinja, the {{ fullname }} contain the complete name two or more words and the value is there, but my code only display the first word.

this is the code:

```html
<div class="form-group">
     <input type="text" name="Fullname" class="form-control" placeholder="Company Name" value={{ fullname }} required />
</div>
```

Let say that the value returned by Database is: juan Perez
it will only display juan, not the complete name.

Comment: Please add the relevant part of your code that isn't working. Better, try to provide a MWE.

Comment: You have to quote it, like other attributes of your input: `value="{{ fullname }}"`

Comment: @ 
β.εηοιτ.βε
Thanks, good to go.:  value="{{ fullname }}" I was missing the quotes.

Comment: Yes, missing quotes. Otherwise your code is `value=juan Perez` and of course only Juan is shown by the browser, whereas a source inspector would indicate that you have an unknown attribute Perez